# How to make a test on a regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, django, unit-testing, testing

I have just started to make tests on my web application.

Firstly, I'm not sure if it's necessary to run tests on regex model fields (like the one in my code), secondly, if the testing is necessary, how can I do it?

I've already tried this solution:  [Unit Tests pass against regex validator of models in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968898/unit-tests-pass-against-regex-validator-of-models-in-django) but it's not working.

cf field needs a 16 chars string, but my function test_cf_max_length() is returning seller object even if the cf entered is wrong(<16 chars)

models.py

```py
class Seller(User):
    cf = models.CharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{16}$', message='Social Security Number', code='nomatch')], max_length=16)
    iban = models.CharField(validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^.{27}$', message='IBAN', code='nomatch')], max_length=27)
    is_seller = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

tests.py

```py
def setUpTestData(cls):
    Seller.objects.create(username='clara', cf='12345690123456', iban='123456789012345678901234567')


def test_cf_max_length(self):
    seller = Seller.objects.get(id=1)
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        if seller.full_clean():
            seller.save()
    self.assertEqual(Seller.objects.filter(id=1).count(), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/validators/#how-validators-are-run

> Note that validators will not be run automatically when you save a model, but if you are using a ModelForm, it will run your validators on any fields that are included in your form.

And regarding the necessity of testing, this case clearly shows you that it make sense to write them.